# python: how to store data in mongo via http put

Tags: python, mongodb, rest, bottle

I am trying to create a REST API application using python bottle framework

I'd like to be able to insert data in mongodb via HTTP PUT request.

So far I am able to get response from the mongodb using HTTP GET.

Please help me INSERT data in mongodb via HTTP PUT.

JSON format I have to insert as follows:

```
{"_id": "id_1", "key_1": "value_1"}
```

[i am using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client-appl/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to get and put http response]

```
import json
import bottle
from bottle import route, run, request, abort
from pymongo import Connection

connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.mydatabase

@route('/documents', method='PUT')
def put_document():
    data = request.body.readline()
    if not data:
        abort(400, 'No data received')
    entity = json.loads(data)
    if not entity.has_key('_id'):
        abort(400, 'No _id specified')
    try:
        db['documents'].save(entity)
    except ValidationError as ve:
        abort(400, str(ve))

@route('/documents/:id', method='GET')
def get_document(id):
    entity = db['documents'].find_one({'_id':id})
    if not entity:
        abort(404, 'No document with id %s' % id)
    return entity

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting and tell us what you have tried, what you would expect, what did not work, how does the error message look like, ...

Comment: I want to insert the data in the following format {"_id": "doc1", "name": "Test Document 1"}

Answer (score 2):

The following revised version of your code seems to work as you intended:

```
import json

from bottle import route, run, request, abort
from pymongo import Connection


connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)
db = connection.mydatabase


@route('/documents', method='PUT')
def put_document():
    data = request.body.readline()
    print(data)
    if not data:
        abort(400, 'No data received')
    entity = json.loads(data)
    if not entity.has_key('_id'):
        abort(400, 'No _id specified')
    try:
        db.documents.insert(entity)
    except ValidationError as ve:
        abort(400, str(ve))


@route('/documents/<_id>', method='GET')
def get_document(_id):
    entity = db.documents.find_one({'_id': _id})
    if not entity:
        abort(404, 'No document with id %s' % _id)
    return entity

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

I have *MongoDB* running and executing the script, start the server on `localhost` port `8080`, I then execute the following commands on a shell with the expected results:

```sh
$ echo '{"_id": "id_1", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2"}' | curl -X PUT -d @- http://localhost:8080/documents
$ curl http://localhost:8080/documents/id_1
{"_id": "id_1", "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2"}
```

Comment: what you are doing is write , but i have to send http put request to the my localhost server so that it will insert the data in momgodb

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand your comment. The answer I have provided, based on your code, is doing exactly that: running on _localhost_ and inserting and retrieving data from a _MongoDB_ instance running on _localhost_. Can you please explain more clearly why it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: The same thing you are doing by executing curl in the terminal.       i have to do it by using put method from browser

Comment: The `curl` command lines were just to demonstrate that the server works. It will work just as well from the browser. You can test it with the Chrome extension you've mentioned in your question and it will work exactly the same. The purpose of the question the server side, which is solved, not the client.